# Unable to connect over SSL

Tags: rundeck

I've configured SSL - When I attempt to connect remotely I get Connection Aborted
When I curl locally I get a 7 byte Binary output.

I thought it might be a TLS/Cipher issue but I confirmed that I was able to locally connect using TLs1.2 adn a cipher that was supported on my remote system.

When I connected remotely I had debug enabled

Remote Resp (I have 500 lines of logs, I think I pulled the relevant lines , happy to share more)
I've added line feeds for readability:

```
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,714] DEBUG ssl.SslConnection [qtp1674423837-59] - fill starting handshake SslConnection@2ced3116::SocketChannelEndPoint@36b01040{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=8/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@2ced3116{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=0/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@1367423a{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=10/30000}=>HttpConnection@18d4ac9[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@700897b5{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@465a8526{s=HttpChannelState@d305c1{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}

rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,714] DEBUG ssl.SslConnection [qtp1674423837-32] - fill starting handshake SslConnection@4ed75ddd::SocketChannelEndPoint@6affba44{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=8/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@4ed75ddd{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=0/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@2706acc1{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=10/30000}=>HttpConnection@57a0965f[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@319bf204{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@2bbe12ed{s=HttpChannelState@434babd1{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}

rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,716] DEBUG ssl.SslConnection [qtp1674423837-32] - <fill f=-1 uf=false SslConnection@4ed75ddd::SocketChannelEndPoint@6affba44{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=10/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@4ed75ddd{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@2706acc1{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=12/30000}=>HttpConnection@57a0965f[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@319bf204{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@2bbe12ed{s=HttpChannelState@434babd1{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}

rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,716] DEBUG ssl.SslConnection [qtp1674423837-59] - <fill f=-1 uf=false SslConnection@2ced3116::SocketChannelEndPoint@36b01040{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=10/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@2ced3116{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@1367423a{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=12/30000}=>HttpConnection@18d4ac9[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@700897b5{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@465a8526{s=HttpChannelState@d305c1{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}

rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,716] DEBUG server.HttpConnection [qtp1674423837-32] - HttpConnection@57a0965f::DecryptedEndPoint@2706acc1{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=12/30000} filled -1 HeapByteBuffer@380084ed[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,716] DEBUG server.HttpConnection [qtp1674423837-59] - HttpConnection@18d4ac9::DecryptedEndPoint@1367423a{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=12/30000} filled -1 HeapByteBuffer@21d7ee02[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,716] DEBUG server.HttpConnection [qtp1674423837-32] - HttpConnection@57a0965f::DecryptedEndPoint@2706acc1{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=12/30000} parse HeapByteBuffer@380084ed[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} {}
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,716] DEBUG server.HttpConnection [qtp1674423837-59] - HttpConnection@18d4ac9::DecryptedEndPoint@1367423a{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=12/30000} parse HeapByteBuffer@21d7ee02[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} {}
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,718] DEBUG io.AbstractEndPoint [qtp1674423837-32] - close DecryptedEndPoint@2706acc1{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=15/30000}
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,718] DEBUG io.AbstractEndPoint [qtp1674423837-59] - close DecryptedEndPoint@1367423a{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=15/30000}
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,718] DEBUG io.AbstractEndPoint [qtp1674423837-32] - close(null) DecryptedEndPoint@2706acc1{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=15/30000}
rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,718] DEBUG io.AbstractEndPoint [qtp1674423837-59] - close(null) DecryptedEndPoint@1367423a{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=15/30000}

rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,718] DEBUG ssl.SslConnection [qtp1674423837-32] - shutdownOutput: SslConnection@4ed75ddd::SocketChannelEndPoint@6affba44{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=13/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@4ed75ddd{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@2706acc1{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26407,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=15/30000}=>HttpConnection@57a0965f[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@319bf204{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@2bbe12ed{s=HttpChannelState@434babd1{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} oshut=false, ishut=true

rundeck.log:[2022-10-31T11:23:39,718] DEBUG ssl.SslConnection [qtp1674423837-59] - shutdownOutput: SslConnection@2ced3116::SocketChannelEndPoint@36b01040{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=13/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@2ced3116{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@1367423a{l=/10.18.64.7:4443,r=/10.18.155.9:26413,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=15/30000}=>HttpConnection@18d4ac9[p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@700897b5{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@465a8526{s=HttpChannelState@d305c1{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} oshut=false, ishut=true
```

Local Curl Req/Resp

```
curl localhost:4443 -k --output /tmp/curl
^U^C^C^@^B^BP
```

I tired to connect via ssl, and after hardcoding the "RUNDECK_WITH_SSL flag (even though it said that wasn't needed for RHEL, I seemed to have made an initial connection - but it doesn't display the welcome page

Comment: Could you share how you configured the rundeck SSL? Any steps? Does rundeck manages the SSL cert or is delegated to a web server / LB?

Comment: This is a DEV/POC environment so I've just used the self-signed cert. I used the steps here:
https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/ssl.htm

I did get a little further - I converted the keystore to a PKCS12 and restarted and then was able to get a "Connection Reset by Peer" thrown from jetty - so i think my corpr infra is blocking it for some reason (Maybe they don't like self-signed certs over non-standard ports)

Comment: Do you see any clue in the service.log file? (not rundeck.log).

Comment: Yeah - that's where I saw the Connection Reset by Peer message - I installed a reverse proxy to forward 443 to the non-standard port and that worked so I'm gonna blame this on my company :)

Comment: Good news then! please add the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer here (sorry for the delay on this) WAS corporate net sec policy. We installed nginx to forward requests from 443 to 4440 and that seemed to get us over the hurdle